# Can we combine 2 measures into one?

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

My data view is look like below:

[image]

To do the SUM of salary group by employee id I have created 2 measure as below:

```
Measure = MAXX(DISTINCT(Employee1[EmployeeId]),MAX(Employee1[Salary]))
SumSalary = SUMX(DISTINCT(Employee1[Salary]),[Measure])
```

I tried as below but it does not work. Showing wrong values in Power BI.

```
SumSalary = SUMX(DISTINCT(Employee1[Salary]),MAXX(DISTINCT(Employee1[EmployeeId]),MAX(Employee1[Salary])))
```

Is there any other way to combine those measures?

Comment: So you want the sum of all distinct salaries or do you want the sum of the employee salaries where you don't double count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something along these lines:

```
TotalSalary = SUMX(
                  SUMMARIZE(Employee1,
                      Employee1[EmployeeId],
                      "EmployeeSalary", MAX(Employee1[Salary])),
                  [EmployeeSalary])
```

This first groups them by `EmployeeId`, taking the maximum salary for that ID, and then sums the salaries for each employee.